# Reemplazar valores en string

Tags: python, regex

Partamos en que tengo un string de la siguiente forma `'[a,b,"abc",f,9,"998f"]'` y que tengo un diccionario `{"a":5,"b":9,"f":3}`. Lo que yo quiero es reemplazar las letras que **no** están entre comillas, es decir `a`,`b` y `f`, por los valores que se encuentran en el diccionario y que el resultado sea un string `'[5,9,"abc",3,9,"998f"]'`.

Lo que había echo de primera era esto:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

dict_vars = {"a":5,"b":9,"f":3}

expresion = '[a,b,"abc",f,9,"998f"]'

expresion = [literal_eval(x) if '"' in x or x.isnumeric() else dict_vars[x] for x in expresion.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")]
print(expresion)
```

Esto me funciona, pero surge el problema al tener un string de esta forma `'[[a],[b],"999", 9, [a,f,8]]'` o similares.

Yo pensé en usar una expresión regular para detectar las letras que no estén entre comillas y obtener un iterador con `re.finditer()` e ir reemplazando las coincidencias con las que se encuentran en el diccionario. Pero sinceramente no me llevo bien con las regex y aún no puedo desarrollar una.

El string de entrada simula una lista en python por lo que cuyas letras sin comillas son tomadas como variables y por eso debo de reemplazarlas para luego usar `literal_eval` y transformarla en una verdadera lista python. Si se les ocurre una forma diferente de hacerlo me gustaría verla ^_^.

Voy dando unos ejemplos de entrada y salida teniendo en cuenta el diccionario anterior:

- `'[a, [b,1], 0, "989", f]'` -> `'[5, [9,1], 0, "989", 3]'`
- `'[[[a], "b"], "a,b,c", "f", [[[f]]]]'` -> `'[[[5], "b"], "a,b,c", "f", [[[3]]]]'`
- `'["ab.c,d", "f,f",[f, [a],[b]]]'` -> `'["ab.c,d", "f,f", [3, [5],[9]]]'`

Comment: `eval(expresion, dict_vars)` te sirve?

Comment: -_- pues sí. No sé como no lo pensé antes

Comment: pero como dijo Candid a mano limpia sería mejor :D

Answer (score 2):

#### Solución

Usando el método ofrecido por Abulafia en los comentarios y validando que no haya nada inesperado con el modulo `ast` (que además de su famoso literal_eval nos permite analizar código de Python) podrás usar un sistema seguro para lograr lo que buscas.

El modulo ast nos permite analizar el código de Python en forma de nodos. Cada nodo significa algo de Python. En mi código se validan los siguientes nodos:

- [ast.Constant](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.Constant) Coincide con todo valor constante (cadenas, numeros, flotantes, tuplas si todos sus valores son constantes, bytes, etc).
- [ast.Name](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.Name) se trata de un nombre de variable.
- [ast.List](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.List) se trata de una lista. Nota: las listas creadas con la función list son [ast.Call](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.Call).

También hacemos una clase derivada de [ast.NodeVisitor](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) para poder visitar con más belleza los diversos nodos.

---

```
import ast

class Validator(ast.NodeVisitor):
    # Si el nodo es una lista, visita sus items
    def visit_List(Self, node):
        for item in node.elts:
            Self.visit(item)

    # Si el nodo es una constante, se asegura de que no sea una tupla ni un frozenset.
    def visit_Constant(Self, node):
        if(isinstance(node.value, (tuple, frozenset))):
            raise ValueError("La cadena a evaluar no puede contener tuplas ni frozensets.")

    # Si el nodo es un nombre de variable, se asegura que esta variable solamente se cargue.
    def visit_Name(Self, node):
        if(not isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Load)):
            raise ValueError("No puede haber asignaciones ni borrados de variables.")

    # Si es cualquier otro nodo, da un error de nodo invalido.
    def generic_visit(Self, node):
        raise ValueError(f"Nodo invalido: {node!r}")

def valide_and_eval(cadena, variables):
    # proceso el codigo y obtengo su cuerpo.
    processed_code = ast.parse(cadena, mode="eval").body

    # Creo el validador
    validator = Validator()

    # Valido el código procesado
    validator.visit(processed_code)

    # si no sucedió ningún error, evaluo la expresión.
    return eval(cadena, variables)

dic = {"a":5,"b":9,"f":3}

print('[a, [b,1], 0, "989", f]')
print(valide_and_eval('[a, [b,1], 0, "989", f]', dic))
print()
print('["ab.c,d", "f,f",[f, [a],[b]]]')
print(valide_and_eval('["ab.c,d", "f,f",[f, [a],[b]]]', dic))
print()
print('[[[a], "b"], "a,b,c", "f", [[[f]]]]')
print(valide_and_eval('[[[a], "b"], "a,b,c", "f", [[[f]]]]', dic))
```

Que produce:

```
[a, [b,1], 0, "989", f]
[5, [9, 1], 0, '989', 3]

["ab.c,d", "f,f",[f, [a],[b]]]
['ab.c,d', 'f,f', [3, [5], [9]]]

[[[a], "b"], "a,b,c", "f", [[[f]]]]
[[[5], 'b'], 'a,b,c', 'f', [[[3]]]]

[a := 'b', c()]

ValueError: Nodo invalido: <_ast.NamedExpr object at 0x040C3370>
```

---

El módulo ast es muy bueno! Te invito a leer su documentación para entenderlo mejor: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html. Nota: la documentación en español está incompleta.

#### Un aviso

Si es posible trata de evitar usar regex para analizar cualquier lenguaje de programación. Eso puede tener fallos. Por favor lee esto en la pagina inglesa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not. Habla de html pero aplica a todo lenguaje de programación (al menos eso me dijeron en la comunidad inglesa)